# Delete Google App Engine Version

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud Platform project with several GCE instances that I use daily. I decided I wanted to mess around with app engine and deployed a sample version of an application that I would now like to get rid of. While I've disabled the app is there any way to delete it without deleting the entire project? I've tried `appcfg.sh delete_version appengine-dir -V 1` but I get `Bad argument: You must specify a version ID via -V or --version`. I've tried doing `appcfg.sh delete_version appengine-dir --version=1` but get the same thing. I'm going to be really disappointed if I have to download all the data off of my instances and re-deploy the entire project just to get rid of an app engine app which will never be used again. I am aware this is technically speaking a duplicate question but all of the answers I've found are for older versions of app engine and I just get redirected to the new console which doesn't seem to have the same options.

EDIT: Turns out doing `appcfg.sh -A projID -V 1 delete_version appengine-dir` works and doesn't give me any of those errors but I get `Cannot delete the default version of the default module.` I get the feeling I just can't do this at all which I personally find really really dumb.

Comment: I also didn't find a way to deleted default version. App Engine requires at least one version be deployed. I've deployed empty project (which is free) as replacement. I can give example, if this works for you

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Thanks for the response. The application I have deployed and disabled is nothing more than an HTML page that says test. The real reason I want it removed is primarily my OCD. If I never use app engine it'll bug me that I have something deployed there.

Comment: yeah, same here. deployed a simple static html file (instead of previous full featured java module). didn't find any other way

Comment: @IgorArtamonov yea. It's disappointing. Had I known ahead of time I would have made a separate project that I could just throw away when I was done. Oh well.

Comment: btw, an empty module with static files only, doesn't cost anything for you, it's free

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Yea I know. If I could do vhosts I'd probably use app engine instead of tomcat on GCE since it's probably cheaper. Problem is I'm limited to 3 apps.

Comment: oh, you want to delete whole project, not just app engine part? you can do that at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/projects

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I've thought about doing that. It's just too much headache to move all my other stuff

Comment: I don't understand - 1) if you have anything else in this project - just put empty module (as you did), that's it, free, don't use any resources. 2) if you don't have anything (and limited to 3 projects and want free spots) - delete project itself.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov the project is in use. The currently deployed module is empty and disabled. You've already answered my question. What I'm looking to do can't be done and the only issue with that is it'll bug me. There's no technical reason.

Comment: ok, I got it. you just mentioned that you're `limited to 3 apps`. I though you mean you have quota for 3 free gcloud projects, so want to remove some unused

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Oh yea. I was saying I'd use app engine in place of tomcat if I could have more than 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not currently possible to delete the default module of an App Engine application.

There is however an open feature request [Issue 12984](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12984) for this.  Feel free to ***star*** this public issue to support this request and receive updates regarding its progress.

Comment: XD...I'd love to star it...except I'm the one who opened it haha. Although I'd appreciate it if I could get as many stars as I can.

Comment: Thanks for filing said issue in the first place.  We appreciate constructive feedback for the platform.  Technically, this is the appropriate answer to your question despite not being the answer you might have been looking for...

Answer (score 1):

This is what I put in my `cloudbuild.yaml` to delete versions older than count 5.

```
# Remove old GAE versions
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      versions=$(gcloud app versions list \
        --service default \
        --sort-by '~version' \
        --format 'value(VERSION.ID)' | sed 1,5d)
      for version in $versions; do
        gcloud app versions delete "$version" \
          --service default \
          --quiet
      done
```

Answer (score 0):

This can now be accomplished on the command line using:

```
gcloud app versions delete <version-name>
```